# Restore a removed file when still in use

Tags: linux, files, restore

Is there a way to restore/recover a removed file when it's still in use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Linux at least, you can access all files which a process still has open, in `/proc/${pid}/fd`:

```
$ echo Test > removeme
$ sleep 1200 < removeme &
[1] 21954
$ rm removeme
$ ls -l /proc/21954/fd
total 0
lr-x------. 1 skitt skitt 64 Aug 13 17:14 0 -> '/home/skitt/tmp/removeme (deleted)'
lrwx------. 1 skitt skitt 64 Aug 13 17:14 1 -> /dev/pts/7
lrwx------. 1 skitt skitt 64 Aug 13 17:14 2 -> /dev/pts/7
$ cat /proc/21954/fd/0
Test
```

You can `cp` the corresponding file to recover it.